# Jmeter 2.9 HTTP Sampler for PUT not passing parameters

Tags: http, parameters, jmeter, put

I'm using `Jmeter` version 2.9, `HTTP` sampler to test my rest services.

The GET and POST are working without any issues, where as PUT is not passing any parameters in the request to the server.

I verified it with view results in tree.

Any reasons on why this is happening and work around this issue?

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me. Based on what I read on internet, there were different solutions suggested:

- Changing Content-Encoding to UTF-8
- Pass the PUT parameters in the "body data" tab (as opposed to passing them in tabular format in the "Parameters" tab)
- Setting **Content-Type** header to **application/json** in the HTTP Header Manager
- Passing the parameters via a file (even if this were to work, how would you pass dynamic values?)
- passing it as **POST** with a combination of above points.

**WHAT WORKED FOR ME** is this combination: **Set content type to application/json** + **Pass parameters as "JSON" in the **body data** tab (below is an example)

I did not need to specify UTF-8 or anything else.

**EXAMPLE JSON PARAMETER BODY:**
*{"title":"JMeterTitle","preMortar":"JMeterPre","postMortar":"JMeterPost"}*

Answer (score 2):

I am using `JMeter 2.11` and I had the same problem. I solved in this way:

1) Setting Content-Type header similar to that you are using in your api method(Example: `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` etc.) in the HTTP Header Manager.

2)In HTTP Request. **Body Data** should look like this:

`KEY=VALUE&KEY=VLAUE&KEY=VLAUE&KEY=VLAUE.......`

Answer (score 1):

Pass parameters in path field using:

> ?name=value&name2=value2

and body in Raw Post body.
if it doesn't work report a bug .

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, try see the logs.

Had a similar problem.
I was using wrongly the "Content-enconding" field as it were the HTTP 
Content-Type param. They are not related.

If you need to set Content-Type=application/json you have to use a "HTTP Header Manager" config element.

After setting correctly Content-enconding to UTF-8 the put request started to work.

[image: jmeter]

Answer (score 0):

You should add a parameter with an empty name (in the "parameters" tab).

If the problem persists use the result tree view to analyze the request settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JMeter 2.13 and facing with similar problem. This is How I've solved it:

- Setting **Content-Type** header to **text/plain** in the HTTP Header Manager
- Changing **Content-Encoding** to **UTF-8**
- In the parameters tab, add the params **without name** and separated with ampersand character (**&**)

[Screenshot JMeter PUT request example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpwfL.png)

Hope it helps!

Comment: [Link to jmeter-archive](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/How-to-send-HTTP-PUT-request-using-Jmeter-td5719869.html#a5726673)