# Patch Method returns 404 in Jemter

Tags: web-services, jmeter, postman, web-api-testing

I am trying to send patch request using jmeter(which works by postman), i.e i have copied the request from postman, i am using correct header authorization etc still it returns the error 404. 
I am using jmeter version 3.2.

```
PATCH https://dev-api.test.com/walk/v1/walks/77/test/2017101609260477/test/781281212?apikey=ZwQGsEN0f65kORZ8EVQlJWA2bGNbHls0

    PATCH data:
    {
    "status":"Available"
    }

    [no cookies]

    Request Headers:
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: application/json
    Authorization: Bearer hhjahsj
    Content-Length: 26
    Host: dev-api.test.com
    User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_131)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should choose in HTTP Request Advanced tab Client implementations choose `HTTPClient4`

If Java implementations is taken, [PATCH](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) not supported:

> It supports only the following methods: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE and TRACE

Also Notice:

The PUT and PATCH method body must be provided as one of the following:

> The PUT and PATCH method body must be provided as one of the
>   following:
>
> 1. define the body as a file with empty Parameter name field; in which
>      case the MIME Type is used as the Content-Type
> 2. define the body as
>      parameter value(s) with no name
> 3. use the Body Data tab
>      GET, DELETE, PUT and PATCH require a Content-Type.
>      If not using a file, attach a Header Manager to the sampler and define
>      the Content-Type there.

Also according to [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322554/jmeter-how-to-send-parameters-with-patch-method/32323040#32323040) issue add parameters in query as:

> https://example.com/user/accountemail=example%40example.com&password=12345678

**EDIT**

You can also use [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) plugin which support also an HTTP

> non standard method

**EDIT 2**

You can sent PATCH request to test website: https://postman-echo.com/patch